# Any way to center the image?

Tags: feature-request

Currently when an image is inserted/linked into any question or answer it goes to the left side. Even the `<center>` HTML tag doesn't works for this. It would be good if the images stays at center.

Comment: It's a feature. Imagine some users centering all their text, just because they can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, center your image before using an image editing application. Take 640 px (roughly) as the width of the answer `div`.

[image]

Comment: FYI: images always have a `max-width: 640px;` applied to them, so use 640px as the width. If you're really pedantic about getting the image in the *exact* center remember that it will effectively have a 20px margin on the right, so offset slightly to compensate. I suspect this will also have negative ramifications for mobile and other small-screen devices.

Comment: Ah, fair enough! Just a hack anyway...

Comment: Indeed, as was my suggestion. :)

Comment: @DMA57361 I just tested on `slhck`'s image hack: *on the mobile version of the site, it's still centred*. Granted, the whole thing is shrunk to the point of barely-readable with the same proportion of whitespace to keep it centred, which is why I typically make the image a link to the picture in my answers.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to centre an image that isn't a bit hackish, it's not functionality that is provided.

---

If you really must, you *could* just precede the image by a load of `&nbsp;` - or wrap the image in `<pre>` tags and use normal spaces - to manually add spacing to give the *appearance* of the image being centred (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/is-it-possible-to-horizontally-center-an-image-in-sofu) MSO post for examples).

However, this might cause problems for viewers on mobile devices and maybe tablets (not tested, but I just have a suspicion...), so I'd actually advice against this - just leave the images where they are.